Help with a field update formula on an Approval Process
I have a process where the Business would like a field updated on initial submission. The criteria are as follows:

The field to be updated is Pending Approver
There are two record types that, depending on opp record type, Pending Approver would update to two different managers

unless, one of those two managers are submitters
then it would update to another two managers.


And if the submitter's manager is a certain manager, the pending approver will be the submitter's manager.

This is the formula I came up with but is not working:
IF(
    Opp_Record_Type__c = "*" && $User.ManagerId <> "*", 
    "Courtney Palladino", 
    IF(
        Opp_Record_Type__c = "*" && $User.ManagerId <> "*", 
        "AM Manager", 
        IF(
            Opp_Record_Type__c = "*", 
            "Michelle Gedney", 
            IF(
                $User.LastName = "Palladino" || $User.LastName = "Gedney", 
                "Haydee Gamboa & Frank Amendola", 
                ""
            )
        )
    )
)


Hi Gabe, welcome to SFSE. Can you be a little more specific than "not working?" Detailed explanations of behavior, verbatim error messages, etc. can help the community better assist you.

I've taken out a bit of language in the hopes that it makes things a bit clearer, feel free to add it back in if I took something important out.

Hi Frank, the part that is not working is the IF statement for user last name. If the user last name is Palladino, it should make the pending approver Frank and Haydee but it still updates the field to Courtney

Based on what you're saying in the comments, it's just a matter of ordering/specificity.
This analogy probably won't land for many people, but... it's like firewall rules. The first match wins, so go in order from most specific to least specific.
In your existing formula, "Palladino" and "Gedney" are the last things you end up checking. Your formula returns a result before you get to that check. Formulas only execute once (they don't re-evaluate after the first value is checked) so you get stuck with "Palladino" or "Gedney" instead of going to Haydee and Frank.
Since your output are (generally) names, looking for specific names is the most specific you can be. So...
IF(
    $User.LastName = "Palladino" || $User.LastName = "Gedney", 
    "Haydee Gamboa & Frank Amendola",
    IF(
        (Opp_Record_Type__c = "Rec Type 1" || Opp_Record_Type__c = "Rec Type 2") && $User.ManagerId <> "*", 
        "Courtney Palladino", 
        IF(
            (Opp_Record_Type__c = "Rec Type 1" || Opp_Record_Type__c = "Rec Type 2") && $User.ManagerId <> "*", 
            "AM Manager", 
            IF(
                Opp_Record_Type__c = "Rec Type 1" || Opp_Record_Type__c = "Rec Type 2", 
                "Michelle Gedney",              
                ""
            )
        )
    )
)

I'm assuming that the Opp_Record_Type__c = "*" expands to (Opp_Record_Type__c = "Rec Type 1" || Opp_Record_Type__c = "Rec Type 2")
If that's the case, and further assuming that you only want to use Haydee/Frank when the opp record type is one of those two, then it makes that comparison used in all branches. Something that's used in all branches is something that can be factored out (just like math), so I think your end result here looks like
IF(
    /* Factoring common things out takes precedence over the "most specific" rule */
    /* Since we do this check here, everything in the  "then" part of the */
    /*   outermost IF() "inherits" this check, so to say */
    Opp_Record_Type__c = "Rec Type 1" || Opp_Record_Type__c = "Rec Type 2",
    IF(
        /* Specific -> General */
        $User.LastName = "Palladino" || $User.LastName = "Gedney", 
        "Haydee Gamboa & Frank Amendola",
        IF(
            $User.ManagerId <> "something", 
            "Courtney Palladino", 
            IF(
                /* Your obfuscation makes it hard to know precisely what to do here */
                /* You may want to switch "AM Manager" and "Michelle"'s positions */
                $User.ManagerId <> "something else?", 
                "AM Manager", 
                "Michelle Gedney"
            )
        )
    ),
    /* Blank value when the opp rec type isn't one of the two chosen values */
    ""
)


Thank you Derek, that was it!
